# Search for a text combination and then moving its next 2 cells to the other table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Alright, I have 3 tables, from the first, the value of 2 cells is taken and brought in the 3rd table and from the 3rd table the sum of those cells is added in one cell and counted in another. Ex: First table Jacob 1 Apple (written 2 times in 2 different rows). This will go in the 3rd table just the same then numbers will be counted (2 numbers) and written in the 2nd first cell and also added and written in another cell. I want to redo this as many times I add a new name or number it kind of breaks the formulas and the formulas start stealing from the above cell or from the below.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a0NIeA2xlDzpK-C4Mvq1UANfYdUHc9gHli6U3v2L6r8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in range **E:K**
paste this formula into **E1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(A1:C, 
 "select A,count(A),sum(B) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  label count(A)'DS events total',sum(B)'Overall attendees'", 0),
 QUERY(IFERROR(QUERY(A1:C, 
 "select sum(B) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  pivot C", 0)*1, 
 {"Overal BTs", "Overal CTs", "Overal FTs", "Overal PTs"}), 
 "select Col4,Col1,Col3,Col2", 1)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I would probably ask for too much now but would it be possible to add all this into an if then formula and say that if the name from the Name list is not found add the name and a line of 0 0 0 0 0, else the script you just wrote.

Comment: E column contains all names - always

Comment: Only the ones that appear on the 1st table